# Replace values from a column with value corresponding to vector with matches

Tags: r, string, dataframe, replace, str-replace

I have a dataframe and in the column "roles", each row has a value of "students" or "teacher". I want to replace these values with "st" or "te" accordingly.

```
roles_complete <- c("students","teacher")
roles_standard <- c("st", "te")
data$roles <- stri_replace_all(data$roles, regex= roles_complete, roles_standard)
```

Weirdly, this only changes some values.

```
    roles
1   st
2   students
3   teacher
4   te
5   st
6   students
7   teacher
8   te
9   st
10  students
11  teacher
12  te
```

I'm obviously doing something wrong with the conditions I've inserted in the stri_replace but the documentation is not very clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### `dplyr` package

You can use `recode()` in `dplyr`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(roles = recode(roles, "students" = "st", "teacher" = "te"))
```

If you have assigned roles to variables, then you can take a ***named vector*** as input.

```
roles_complete <- c("students", "teacher")
roles_standard <- c("st", "te")

df %>%
  mutate(roles = recode(roles, !!!setNames(roles_standard, roles_complete)))
```

---

#### `stringr` package

`str_replace_all()` in `stringr` also can take a named vector as input.

```
library(stringr)

df$roles <- str_replace_all(df$roles, setNames(roles_standard, roles_complete))
```

---

#### `base` solution

```
df$role <- factor(df$role, labels = c("st", "te"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Is that `stringi` package? It seems to me that only sequence (a vector) of "students" and "teacher" in a row is replaced. So when there are "students" and "students" in a row, it remains unchanged.

If you can switch to package `stringr`, the function `str_replace_all()` allows you to define exactly how to replace the matched patterns:

```
library(stringr)
data <- c("students", "teacher", "students", "teacher")
str_replace_all(data, c("students" = "st", "teacher" = "te"))
```

So for your case:

```
data$roles <- str_replace_all(data$roles, c("students" = "st", "teacher" = "te"))
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is only a test run script and the actual use will be to replace 31 different unique values. Would there be an alternative to writing all 31 matches in there?

Comment: @AarónGzz There'll be certainly some solution! But I need to ask: do you mean to automatically create a named vector for 31 unique values? Or i it OK to only shorten all the values to 2 characters?

Comment: Thanks Petr. I ended up creating a vector with all 31 unique values and then inputing into a recode() with setNames().

Comment: Great, @AarónGzz, thanks for your feedback, your final solution is really elegant and simple!

Answer (score 0):

Usually R interprets character vectors as factors. If that is the case in your data set:

```
data <- data.frame(roles = sample(c("students","teacher"), 12, replace = TRUE))
levels(data$roles)
# [1] "students" "teacher" 
levels(data$roles) <- c("st", "te")
levels(data$roles)
# [1] "st" "te"
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest Base R way, assuming each level is either student or teacher as is stated in OP:

```
levels(data$roles) <- substr(levels(data$roles), 1, 2)
```

Data

```
data <-
  data.frame(roles = sample(c("students", "teacher"), 12, replace = TRUE))
```

Answer (score -1):

You could try

```
data$roles <- replace(data$roles,roles_complete,roles_standard)
```

Comment: I think `replace()` cannot work like that. Are you sure your code is feasible in your computer?

Comment: @Darren Tsai, it worked in my tests. I used a string as the input. It was unclear if the data was a factor or not.

Comment: Could you try this example for me? `data <- data.frame(roles = rep(c("students","teacher"), 2), stringsAsFactors = F)`. Thank you

Comment: `replace()` returns a vector of length 6, but my example data just have 4 rows.